# How can I send the records from my sqlite database over network?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I'm writing a bunch of records in the `sqlite` database. Each time stored records count reaches multiple of 10 I'd like to store those 10 records into the object and send to the remote server.

How can I accomlish the task in the separate thread?

Comment: I suggest you to create a `Handler` binded to the separate thread and post `Runnable`'s or messages with your records to it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use http, you can use this example-code.

```
Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
public void run() {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your-url.com");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName", paramValue));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName2", paramValue2));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("error", e.toString());
} 
});
background.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To know about no of rows in table

final String SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample;

you can check the count when it multiple of 10 then you can

you can use this approach if you have date like  any column in table.

final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE + " DESC LIMIT 10"

return db.query(table, columns, selection, null, null, null, orderBy);

now you need to get value from database and pass that values to server.

Answer (score 0):

If all your inserts happened from a single method then you could keep an internal cache of the item ids that are sent to the server and when the set reaches 10, then take those 10 records and perform the send to the server in a background thread.

The pseudo code for this might be something like this...

```
Set<Long> ids = new TreeSet<Long>;

public void insert(Data data) {
   long id = sqlite.insert(data);
   ids.add(id);
   if (ids.size()>=10) {
       postToServer();
   }
}

public void postToServer() {
   // build select statement using the 10 ids in the set.
   // clear the set
   ids.clear();
   // create a new thread and then post your results to the server
   // optionally update those 10 ids in the database to indicate that they have been sent to the server
}
```

The above code only keeps a cache of 10 long values in memory, so tracking that in memory is not huge deal.  And since you have the inserted ids of the records that were inserted, then creating a single select statement using something like

```
select * from TABLE where _ID in (YOUR ID LIST)
```

should be fairly efficient as well.

If you only wanted a single thread to do the posting the server, then you can modify the above logic such that you have a single background thread that monitors the size of the ids Set and when it reaches 10, it will then do the post to the server.